# What are the properties of cycles in a Undirected Graph?

Tags: java, graph

I'm trying to understand this code for detecting a cycle from: 
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/Cycle.java.html

So if a vertex w is not marked or found, continue to run dfs. If it's found and it's not equal to u...   Why am I passing a -1 in the constructor?

I'm confused by the else if (w != u). Why does this lead to a cycle?

```
 public Cycle(Graph G) {
        if (hasSelfLoop(G)) return;
        if (hasParallelEdges(G)) return;
        marked = new boolean[G.V()];
        edgeTo = new int[G.V()];
        for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
            if (!marked[v])
                dfs(G, -1, v);
    }

private void dfs(Graph G, int u, int v) {
        marked[v] = true;
        for (int w : G.adj(v)) {

            // short circuit if cycle already found
            if (cycle != null) return;

            if (!marked[w]) {
                edgeTo[w] = v;
                dfs(G, v, w);
            }

            // check for cycle (but disregard reverse of edge leading to v)
            else if (w != u) {
                cycle = new Stack<Integer>();
                for (int x = v; x != w; x = edgeTo[x]) {
                    cycle.push(x);
                }
                cycle.push(w);
                cycle.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm makes a depth first search on the graph, and marks any vertices it comes across. The method `dfs` is called with the previously visited vertex (`u`) and the currently visited vertex (`v`), with `v` being a successor of `u`. If the next successor of `v` is unmarked (`if (!marked[w])`) the search continues. Otherwise we found a circle.

However if there is an edge directed in both directions, this implementation does *not* count it as circle. `w` is a neighbor of of `v`. If it is `u` itself (the precedessor of `v`) we have this very case. Therefore the code checks that this is *not* the case (`w != u`), ie we have *not* a biderectional edge, and so we *do* have found a circle.

Comment: Can you explain 'u' again? It's not very clear to me.  Should W = U to let us know we've arrived at a ccycle? I don't understand why it's !=.

Comment: The method `dfs` is called with the previously visited vertex (`u`) and the next vertex to visit (`v`), with `v` being a successor of `u`.

Comment: @SimonS please add the explanation to your answer, don't write it in the comments!

Comment: @pss hope its fine now

Comment: having some problems with following the debugger.  if i had 3 verteices with edges (0,1), (1,2), (2,0) - how would W!=u?

Comment: Thanks, i traced it out on paper. Makes sense now.

Comment: Understanding that it's checking to make sure the edge is not bi-directional was the key for me.